# How to use 1.7159 * tanh(2/3 * x) as activation function?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a simple neural network and it works with the logistic function as activation function. Now I want to avoid the saturation problem by substituting the logistic function by the hyperbolic tangent:

```
#define SIGMOID(x) (1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*x)) 
#define DSIGMOID(S) (0.666666667/1.7159*(1.7159-(S))*(1.7159+(S)))
```

But the network never converges, the MSE stays the same throughout the training.
Here's my training samples:

```
double training_data[][4]={
            {0, 0,  0,  -1},
            {0, 0,  1,  1},
            {0, 1,  0,  1},
            {0, 1,  1,  -1},
            {1, 0,  0,  1},
            {1, 0,  1,  -1},
            {1, 1,  0,  -1},
            {1, 1,  1,  1}};
```

The network does converge if I use the original (non-scaled) hyperbolic tangent function, that is:

```
#define SIGMOID(x) (tanh(x))
#define DSIGMOID(S) (1-((S)*(S)))
```

Do I miss something? E.g. Scaling the output to match the range (-1.7159, 1.7159) or anything?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your programming language, is it C?  In MatLab many functions that work with or respond to built-in (libraried) functions need to be expressed in vector notation.  Instead of using the scalar multiplication "*", it is more desirable to use the vectorized ".*" operator.  This improves execution speed substantially.

Comment: 2/3 will give a better approximation than 0.666666667 in most languages.... Presumably of little consequence, but best to do it properly.

Comment: @EngrStudent This is C, no Matlab

Comment: @NickCox There's no real difference between 0.666666667 and 2/3. But using 2/3 is more expensive because the computer will have perform additional calculation. Most people will just hardcode it that way.

Comment: The first example I Googled used a different approximation. More importantly, I suspect all you need to do is to calculate the best approximation to 2/3 just once and define it as a real constant if the expense worries you. The details will depend on your language.

Comment: Does the function require a range from -1 to +1

Comment: @EngrStudent No it's not required, however I need the scaled hyperbolic tangent to avoid near-extreme saturation. And the scaled function maps the output to the range of (-1.7159, 1.7159).

Comment: The derivative of the sigmoid is a hyperbolic secant.  $ 1.14393 sech^2 \left( \frac {2x}{3}\right)$  When you say DSIGMOID, do you mean the derivative?  If you get the slope wrong then gradient descent methods tend to not converge well.

Comment: @EngrStudent yes DSIGMOID means Derivative of the Sigmoid function. I also have commented on your answer below, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: DSIGMOID calculates the derivative of SIGMOID with respect to the input of SIGMOID. However, it expects the the output of SIGMOID as argument. Did you use it that way?

Comment: @alfa Yes I did.

Answer (score 3):

When I plot using the following R-code:

```
x <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, by = 0.01 )
y <- (0.666666667/1.7159*(1.7159-(x))*(1.7159+(x)))
y2 <- (1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*x)) 

plot(x,y2,col = "red")
points(x,y)
```

I get the following plot:
[image: plot of the give expressions]

One of these is a sigmoid (red), one is not a great derivative (black).  Notice the negative values.  This is going to define a radius of convergence that shoots Newtons-methods toward infinity.

Now using this R-code:

```
x <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, by = 0.01 )
y <- 1.14393*(1/cosh(2*x/3))^2
y2 <- (1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*x)) 

plot(x,y2,col = "red", type = "b")
points(x,y)
```

I get this plot:
[image: updated plot of expressions]

It is a more plausible graph of the derivative(black) for the sigmoid(red).

This was fun: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=3e6e161954c6b908db7770bf73f94be7).

Edit:

Here are some basics on Tanh and friends.

1. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html
2. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicCosine.html
3. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSine.html

Please notice in link 1 that the derivative of Hyperbolic Tangent is pow( hyperbolic_secant,2) and not pow( hyperbolic_cosine,2).

Comment: I don't know what a hyperbolic secant is, but the derivative of `f(x) = tanh(x)` is `f'(x) = 1-pow(tanh(x), 2)`. The formula I use is absolutely correct (because I just copied and paste it from a open source library), so it seems the hyperbolic secant is wrong. I think the problem with my NN has something to do with the output (e.g. remap it from (-1.7159, 1.7159) to (-1, 1)... but I haven't seen anyone do that)

Comment: "absolutely correct" because copied and pasted "from a open source library": would that it were so....

Comment: @NickCox This page tells a different story. Derivative of tanh(x) is 1-pow(tanh(x), 2):
http://math2.org/math/derivatives/more/hyperbolics.htm.
And the library I copied and pasted from is the famous FANN, so it must be absolutely correct. The original tanh(x) works as a proof that I got the derivative correctly

Comment: Hehe.  When there are two mutually exclusive and also true statements then there must be a third statement that resolves them.  If $ D = 1-tanh^2(x)$ and $ D = sech^2(x)$ then $tanh^2(x) + sech^2(x) = 1$.  It is about 1/3 the way down this page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).  Neither of these are the quadratic in the first DSIGMOID.  "(0.666666667/1.7159*(1.7159-(S))*(1.7159+(S)))"  Why is that statement correct?  Within a radius of about 2-miles the flat-world hypothesis is a good approximation to the sphere of the earth.  Counterexamples disprove, examples don't prove.

Comment: Not a good idea to be dogmatic when you don't know key facts.

Comment: As vacuous as the character appeared to be, when Dr. Meredith says "Never forget to check your references" it is brilliant.  For rigor, for mastery of utility, for my own professionalism, I want to test every solver or package to guarantee it gets the basics right.  It takes a little longer, but it does a great job of keeping me from error, both technical and typographical.

Comment: Dr. Meredith quote comes from "Real Genius" - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089886/quotes

Answer (score -1):

FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC

f2M_set_act_function_hidden (ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

f2M_set_act_function_output (ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

Symmetric sigmoid activation function, AKA tanh. One of the most used activation functions.

This activation function gives output that is between -1 and 1.